# Clearing the memory or files after opening using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro that open files in a folder, download data from an add-in, save and close.
This runs fine, but after 10 or 15 files, it gets quite slow. I think it is because Excel still keep previously opened files in the memory. I knew this because I saw the already-opened-and-closed files on the left panel as in the photo below. (the photo is to show where the panel is, I know there is only one file opened with the sheets, but you know what I mean).

My question is: is there a line of code that refresh or clear this temporary memory?

Here is my code:

```
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim filename As String
Dim path_to_save As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim w As Long
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim oFile       As Object
Dim oFSO        As Object
Dim oFolder     As Object
Dim oFiles      As Object


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
StartTime = Timer

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Assign the folder to oFSO
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(myPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files
    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then GoTo ResetSettings


For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    myFile = oFile.Name
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myPath & myFile)
    Set cmd = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Refresh All")
    cmd.Execute
    DoEvents

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code

    wb.Close savechanges:=True


    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents
Next 'oFile

SecondsElapsed = Timer - StartTime
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If you loop openning and working on files, bind the workbooks to a workbook reference, and before the next loop use the reference to close the used workbook. `Dim wb As Workbook` then  `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(WorkbookPath)` and finally, before the loop ends: `wb.Close True` (True means saving the workbook before closing it.

Comment: It'd be good to see your code, might be able to help find the best way to fix it.

Comment: @jamheadart I added the code in the post

Comment: @Damian I do close and save the workbook. But I think somehow those closed workbooks are still there in memory

Comment: If the workbook is still open you'll see it on your projects. The other thing could be the RAM memory loading up... that might be your problem @duckman

Comment: @Damian Yes, how do I fix that?

Comment: That I'm sorry but I don't know how.. When this situation happens to me, for example openning a workbook and filtering a huge OLAP cube which eats like 2GB of ram during the process, the only way I know is to close every open excel and restart the application to free up the memory. Maybe someone else knows a better way but I don't sorry.

Comment: Strange behaviour, at the end of every loop for me, the books close and disappear from the Project window as expected, BUT I had to get rid of the `Set cmd` line because I don't have the add-in. I wonder if the add-in is the thing that's causing the memory hold.

Comment: What version of Excel are you running?

Comment: @Damian haha thank you for the experience. I am doing the same thing. After running a few files, I closed the Excel application, and then run again. Although it does not take much time, knowing how to fix it automatically would be nice

Comment: Excel 2016 I believe. The `cmd` bit is just to refresh the add-in so data is loaded. I am not sure if that would cause the files to be kept in the project explorer

Comment: I'm not sure either but by default when you close a book in Excel it disappears from memory, the add-in might be holding on to it for some reason :/

Comment: Could you try, just out of interest, not using the add-in by commenting out the two lines using the `cmd` bit and see if the books still stay in the project window?

Comment: `Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Refresh All")` .. Is that a commandbar button for a VBA Procedure? ..  Also, in the projects explorer, those are all sheets appearing and not file, Those sheets are added in a single file named "request_AADR.xlsx". That might be result of the command button. If so, check that procedure.

Comment: @NareshBhople that code `Application.....` is a VBA procedure, or just a line of code that refresh the add-in. When this is executed, a small window appears which says "Getting data from server... " with a running percentage bar.
I know the photo is just showing the sheets. That is because I just run the macro and take a picture to show the Project Explorer. After several files, there are multiple workbooks like "request_AADR.xlsx" on the Project Explorer.

Comment: Did you try running the same code without the add-in lines to see if your Excel still persisted the problem?

Comment: This is a known issue.  Have you tried Binding a new Instance of Excel (e.g. `Dim appNewExcel As Object: Set appNewExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`), and doing the Open/Refresh in *that* Instance (`Set wb = appNewExcel.Workbooks.Open(filename:=myPath & myFile)`), and Closing, Destroying, and Recreating it every 5-10 files as a way to free the memory? (`Set wb = Nothing: appNewExcel.Quit: Set appNewExcel=Nothing: DoEvents: Set appNewExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`)

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `Set cmd = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Refresh All"): cmd.Execute` instead of `wb.RefreshAll`?

Comment: Yes, the former (one that i am using would refresh the add in and wait until data is loaded. `wb.RefreshAll` cannot do that

Answer (score 0):

What about add:

```
set cmd = nothing
```

before

```
wb.Close savechanges:=True
```

Comment: it does not do anything. The files are still in Project Explorer

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in Excel with closed Workbooks leaving data in Memory, which can only be cleared by closing and reopening Excel.

The below code uses a late-bound second instance of the Excel application, in an attempt to alleviate this issue; the second instance will be closed and reopened periodically (currently set to every 5 files).

```
Sub SomeName()
    'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim path_to_save As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
    Dim w As Long
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    Dim oFile       As Object
    Dim oFSO        As Object
    Dim oFolder     As Object
    Dim oFiles      As Object

    'NEW CODE
    Dim appXL AS Object, counterFiles AS Long
    counterFiles = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    StartTime = Timer

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    'In Case of Cancel
    NextCode:
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Assign the folder to oFSO
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(myPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files
    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then GoTo ResetSettings


    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        'NEW CODE
        If appXL Is Nothing Then Set appNewExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        DoEvents

        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        myFile = oFile.Name
        Set wb = appNewExcel.Workbooks.Open(filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Update / Refresh workbook
        wb.RefreshAll
        appNewExcel.CalculateFullRebuild
        DoEvents

        'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
        wb.Save
        DoEvents
        wb.Close savechanges:=True


        'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
        'NEW CODE
        Set wb = Nothing
        counterFiles = counterFiles+1
        If counterFiles mod 5 = 0 Then
            appNewExcel.Quit
            Set appNewExcel = Nothing
        End If

        DoEvents
    Next 'oFile

    SecondsElapsed = Timer - StartTime
    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed

    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing

ResetSettings:
    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```